# How can I parse hyperlinks in google spreadsheets with pandas python API?

Tags: python, pandas, parsing, google-sheets

So, I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

SHEET_ID = '12dXJcMY6bs8oqn_cH-zvSglHZ6Ee8DwGm86vFNoEih4'
SHEET_NAME = 'AAPL'
url = f'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{SHEET_ID}/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&sheet={SHEET_NAME}'
df = pd.read_csv(url)

name = df.iloc[:,0].loc[0]
link = df.iloc[:,1].loc[0]
cnprice = df.iloc[:,2].loc[0]
usprice = df.iloc[:,3].loc[0]

print(name,link,cnprice,usprice)
```

And when I run it, I get the following output:

`Air Jordan 1 Dark Mocha Link ¥400 $61.34`

The problem lies in the word "Link" in the output, [in the actual spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12dXJcMY6bs8oqn_cH-zvSglHZ6Ee8DwGm86vFNoEih4/htmlview?usp=sharing#), the word Link is a hyperlink, so it displays as "Link", but upon clicking it it brings you to a specific url.

How would I use pandas or other tools to parse this hyper link?

I tried to run the code mentioned above, getting a result of "Link" as the text from a hyperlink, instead of the actual URL of it.

Comment: I don't know if pandas can do this, but you can do it by using the google sheets API directly (with `requests`) as in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62780104/get-link-inside-href-tag-from-cell-in-google-spreadsheet-gspread . You can probably also do it with the `pygsheets` module which is a wrapper for the API.

Comment: Use something similar to this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/35325799/12846804